# Extract only the numbers at the beginning of each line

Tags: r

I would like to extract only the numbers at the beginning of each line. In the example below the result would be: "2.300,00", "200,00".

```
text1 = "
TEST N:    325              Val:                   1.500,00\r\n

Type: Table\r\n

2.300,00           un      \r\n

//\r\n

description\r\n

200,00           un      mass\r\n"
```

I used the command in R `str_extract_all(text1,"([\\d]+.\\d+.\\d.)")`
But the result was "1.500,00" "2.300,00" "200,00"

I tried too: `str_extract_all(texto1, "(^[\\d]+.\\d+.\\d.)")` but nothing is returned.

Comment: Put a “^” at the beginning of your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `multiline` flag: ie `(?m)`

Use the pattern below

```
text1 <-" TEST N: 325 Val: 1.500,00\r\n\n\nType: Table\r\n\n\n2.300,00 un \r\n\n\n//\r\n\n\ndescription\r\n\n\n200,00 un mass\r\n"

str_extract_all(text1,"(?m)^\\d+\\.?\\d+,?\\d+")
[[1]]
[1] "2.300,00" "200,00"
```

If you can loosen abit, assuming the numbers cannot start with a `.` or `,` then you could do:

```
str_extract_all(text1,"(?m)^[0-9.,]+")
[[1]]
[1] "2.300,00" "200,00"
```

EDIT:

stringr package does have the multiline embeded within it. Using your pattern we could do:

```
str_extract_all(text1, regex("(^[\\d]+.\\d+.\\d.)", multiline = TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "2.300,00" "200,00"
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution gave the desired output. First I found cases where the start of a line was followed by a digit. I then then extracted all the characters from that digit to the first space. This accounts for the multiple commas and periods that appear in some of the values. You could also use the expression

```
    \\n(\\d)[0-9.,]+?(\\s)
```

in place of the one below if you wanted to restrict the potential characters to digits, periods, and commas.

Using str_replace_all generated a list so I unlisted it to return a vector. I then took the spaces (which includes line breaks) out of that vector leaving only the numbers.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
text1 %>%
str_extract_all("\\n(\\d).+?(\\s)") %>%
unlist() %>%
str_remove("\\s")

[1] "2.300,00"  "200,00"
```